# AWK to print every nth line from a file

Tags: awk

i want to print every Nth line of a file using AWK.
i tried modifying the general format :-

`awk '0 == NR % 4' results.txt`

to:-

```
awk '0 == NR % $ct' results.txt
```

where 'ct' is the number of lines that should be skipped.
its not working . can anyone please help me out?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: learn what single quotes do in the shell. in short: no variable expansion.

Comment: Read question 24 in the comp.unix.shell FAQ: http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may want to use:

```
awk -v patt="$ct" 'NR % patt' results.txt
```

#### Explanation

Given a file like the following:

```
$ cat -n a
     1  hello1
     2  hello2
     3  hello3
     4  hello4
     5  hello5
     ...
    37  hello37
    38  hello38
    39  hello39
    40  hello40
```

These are equivalent:

```
$ awk 'NR % 7 == 0' a
hello7
hello14
hello21
hello28
hello35
$ ct=7
$ awk -v patt="$ct" 'NR % patt == 0' a
hello7
hello14
hello21
hello28
hello35
```

Or even

```
$ awk -v patt="$ct" '!(NR % patt)' a
```

Note that the syntax `NR % n == 0` means: number of line is multiple to `n`. If we say `!(NR % patt)`, then this is true whenever `NR % patt` is false, ie, `NR` is multiple of `patt`.

#### Update

As you comment you are using Solaris, instead of default `awk` use the following:

```
/usr/xpg4/bin/awk
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response.. but whn i use it,i'm getting the follwing error:`awk: syntax error near line 1 awk: bailing out near line 1`

Comment: `awk -v pattern="$ctr" 'NR % pattern == 0' res.txt`

Comment: It is working to me. Did you set `ctr` to an integer value beforehand?

Comment: Use `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` instead of normal `awk`. (http://objectmix.com/awk/27239-awk-bailing-out-near-line-1-a.html)

Comment: yes i did.. I did this `ctr=`cat data | grep -i "Record Closed" | wc -l`` where i used it to count the occurance of the pattern "Record Closed" in the file called "data"

Answer (score 4):

How about this:

```
awk -v n="$ct" '0 == NR % n' results.txt
```

or a bit shorter

```
awk -v n="$ct" '!(NR % n)' results.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response.. but whn i use it,i'm getting the follwing error:`awk: syntax error near line 1 awk: bailing out near line 1` what is the problem there?

Answer (score 1):

This do also work, but its not a good practice.

```
awk '!(NR%'$ct')' results.txt
```

This is ok to use:

```
awk '!(NR%n)' n="$ct" results.txt
```

Comment: Never use that first version as you can get bizarre output and/or cryptic error messages depending on the value of the shell variable. The second version is fine, but it was already suggested earlier by a couple of other people.

Comment: Thanks for such a quick response.. but whn i use it,i'm getting the follwing error:`awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1`

Comment: thanks :) can we do the same using nawk? since i use normal awk, i'm not able to execute it. i get a bailing error as i mentioned earlier. kindly help me.